# VSTO Outlook: Detect left mouse up in active window

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I would like to know how can i detect left mouse up in the active window.

I googled but i was not able to find anything.

I don't see any mechanism to subscribe to that event in the active window.

Maybe using Windows API functions but how?

Comment: Why do you need to detect the left mouse up event in the active Outlook window?

Comment: More to the point, do you understand what the (or an) [active window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#active-window) is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trivial way for getting the job done in Outlook. The only possible way is to use Windows API functions like [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) which installs an application-defined hook procedure into a hook chain. You would install a hook procedure to monitor the system for certain types of events. For example, you may find the [MouseProc callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644988(v=vs.85)) helpful.